# Ansible - filter list based on other list

Tags: ansible

Can you please kindly suggest how can I filter one list based on other?

I.e. I have this list (`List1`)

```
{
    "AppName": "My Application",
    "environment": "DEV",
    "key": "myapp",
    "location": "DEV",
    "status": "",
    "version": "1.2.0.1001"
},
{
    "AppName": "My Application",
    "environment": "DEV",
    "key": "myapp",
    "location": "DEV",
    "status": "",
    "version": "1.2.0.1002"
},
{
    "AppName": "My Application",
    "environment": "DEV",
    "key": "myapp",
    "location": "DEV",
    "status": "",
    "version": "1.2.0.1020"
}
```

Also I have the list of versions (`List2`)

```
[
    "1.2.0.1001"
    "1.2.0.1020"
]
```

I would like the resulting list produced from `List1`, with all entries where version is in `List2`
So, in the example final list should be

```
{
    "AppName": "My Application",
    "environment": "DEV",
    "key": "myapp",
    "location": "DEV",
    "status": "",
    "version": "1.2.0.1001"
},
{
    "AppName": "My Application",
    "environment": "DEV",
    "key": "myapp",
    "location": "DEV",
    "status": "",
    "version": "1.2.0.1020"
}
```

I've already tried different options, but i do not know how to do it yet.
Any help will be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to achieve is a good candidate for the use of the [conditional when statement](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement).

And in this case, you can construct a new list with the help of the [set_fact module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html), where the `when` will test that the current item we are looping on have a version that is contained in your desired list of versions:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    results: "{{ (results|default([])) + [item] }}"
  with_items: "{{ applications }}"
  when: item.version in versions
```

So, for a full working example, given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: local
  vars:
    applications:
      - AppName: "My Application"
        environment: "DEV"
        key: "myapp"
        location: "DEV"
        status: ""
        version: "1.2.0.1001"
      - AppName: "My Application"
        environment: "DEV"
        key: "myapp"
        location: "DEV"
        status: ""
        version: "1.2.0.1002"
      - AppName: "My Application"
        environment: "DEV"
        key: "myapp"
        location: "DEV"
        status: ""
        version: "1.2.0.1020"
    versions:
      - 1.2.0.1001
      - 1.2.0.1020  

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ applications }}"

    - debug:    
        msg: "{{ versions }}"

    - name: Constructing the resulting list
      set_fact:
        results: "{{ (results|default([])) + [item] }}"
      with_items: "{{ applications }}"
      when: item.version in versions

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ results }}"
```

The play will look like this

```
~ # ansible-playbook play.yml -i inventory.yml 

PLAY [local] *******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [local]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "AppName": "My Application",
            "environment": "DEV",
            "key": "myapp",
            "location": "DEV",
            "status": "",
            "version": "1.2.0.1001"
        },
        {
            "AppName": "My Application",
            "environment": "DEV",
            "key": "myapp",
            "location": "DEV",
            "status": "",
            "version": "1.2.0.1002"
        },
        {
            "AppName": "My Application",
            "environment": "DEV",
            "key": "myapp",
            "location": "DEV",
            "status": "",
            "version": "1.2.0.1020"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": [
        "1.2.0.1001",
        "1.2.0.1020"
    ]
}

TASK [Constructing the resulting list] *****************************************
ok: [local] => (item={'AppName': 'My Application', 'environment': 'DEV', 'key': 'myapp', 'location': 'DEV', 'status': '', 'version': '1.2.0.1001'})
skipping: [local] => (item={'AppName': 'My Application', 'environment': 'DEV', 'key': 'myapp', 'location': 'DEV', 'status': '', 'version': '1.2.0.1002'}) 
ok: [local] => (item={'AppName': 'My Application', 'environment': 'DEV', 'key': 'myapp', 'location': 'DEV', 'status': '', 'version': '1.2.0.1020'})

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "AppName": "My Application",
            "environment": "DEV",
            "key": "myapp",
            "location": "DEV",
            "status": "",
            "version": "1.2.0.1001"
        },
        {
            "AppName": "My Application",
            "environment": "DEV",
            "key": "myapp",
            "location": "DEV",
            "status": "",
            "version": "1.2.0.1020"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
local                      : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Amazing! It is so easy! Thank you very much! It's working exactly as i expect.